# how to distribute tabBar button's

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a senchatouch tabbar with 3 button docked at the bottom but the 3 button stay centralized how can I distribute this 3 button in my tabbar to each one have like 33% of width?

This is my tabbar:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0semvwywpnsacj/2014-01-03%2015.19.12.png

i want my tabbar looks like this one: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cocoacontrols_production/uploads/control_image/image/2207/iPhone.png
with separeted buttons

Answer (score 2):

In configuration of `Ext.tab.Panel` you can add configuration for `tabBar` into [`tabBar`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-tabBar) config property. There you can set defaults width of `tabBar` tabs to `flex: 1`. Then each tab's width will take same proportion of whole `tabBar` width.

So your tabBar config should be:

```
tabBar: {
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    }  
}
```

See this fiddle for live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2f6

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer to close the question for future reference.